# How to split string and get the preferred value?

Tags: python, split

Look like this, give the position as string type:

`str1 = "0,0|2,5|...|"`

This is the user's input, every position is split by `"|"`, so we don't know the number of positions. I need to store every position to the defined variables `pos1, pos2, ...., pos4...`.

For example:

`pos1 = 0,0  pos2 = 2,5,..., pos4=...`

My question is how could I store all the user input to the defined variables?

How can I do these in a less time complexity?

[image]

Comment: This is a simple problem. What have you tried? Please post your code.

Comment: hint: just use `split("|")` to get points, then use for loop on them to assign.

Comment: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dictionary which each key will be pos (pos1, pos2, etc) and the value will be the corresponding `Pos` object.

Try this:

```
class Pos:
    # make sure you add x,y to your class constructor in order to be able to init it dynamically
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

pos_mapping = {}
pos_list = str1.split("|") # pos_list = ["0,0", "2,5" ...]
for i,p in enumerate(pos_list):
    x,y = p.split(",") # split the position string by comma to extract x,y 
    pos_mapping[f"pos{i+1}"] = Pos(x,y)
```

So if you would like to get `pos2`, just do:

```
pos_mapping["pos2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no reason to have the class constructor without parameters. Let it take `x` and `y` at once:

```
class Pos:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

Now, you can split the string first by pipes and then by commas. Apply `int` to each resulting tuple to convert its elements to numbers. Finally, construct a `Pos` from each tuple:

```
positions = [Pos(*map(int, point.split(","))) 
          for point in str1.split("|")]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, in your screenshot, you didn't declare `ps2 = Pos()`. So the original code would not work at this time.
And one more thing : declare class name in PascalCase. It's a python convention.

you actually asked 3 questions. Let's get in.

> FYI : I assumed that every pos values(x and y) would be integer.

1. How to handle undetermined-sized inputs (in this case, `str1`) ?

you can use `string.split()` built-in python method. It goes like this:

```py
my_str = "Hi, I'm now making answer to your questions"
DELIMITER = " "
my_str.split(DELIMITER) # ['Hi,', "I'm", 'now', 'making', 'answer', 'to', 'your', 'questions']
```

In your case, every pos pair would be divided by vertical line character (`|`).

```py
my_str = "2,0|3,4|7,2|8,6|9,1"
delimiter = "|"
for (x,y) in my_str.split(delimiter):
    print(f'x is {x}, y is {y}')

# the output is:
# 2,0
# 3,4
# 7,2
# 8,6
# 9,1
```

You don't have to worry about the size of pair because `split()` method will split a target chunk into every pair unless you didn't specify `maxsplit` numbers. It's optional parameter of `split()` (python3.8 official docs : https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

After splitting, you can split again on each pair (ex. "2,0").

2. How to store those values (in this case, each POS instances) ?

One of the most simplest way is using python built-in list and its method, `append()`.

```py
storage = []
for num in range(0, 10):
    storage.append(num)
    print(storage)

# the output is :
# [0]
# [0, 1]
# [0, 1, 2]
# [0, 1, 2, 3]
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Because python's list is dynamic array, the storage gets bigger on each `append()`.

In short, you can use python 'list' data structure to store unknown-sized values. (Of course you can store POS instances although I showed only integer case!)

3. How to cut off time complexity ?

I'm not sure on this. I think there would be no critical difference if the number of pairs is less than 10k.

But if size is bigger than that I may use this techniques (and probably gonna use c++ rather than python) :

```py
# notice that this is pseudo code
storage = []

p = pos() 
x, y = 0, 0 # initialize
status = 0 # "what am I working for now?" (0 is for x, 1 is for y)
for character in str1:
    if character is number:
        if status == 0:
            x = 10*x + number(character)
        else: # status == 1
            y = 10*y + number(character)
    elif character is ",":
        p.x = x
        x = 0 # re-initialize
        status = 1 # "x is done"
    else: # status is "|"
        p.y = y
        y = 0 # re-initialize
        status = 0 # "y" is done"
        storage.append(p) # add new instance
        p = pos() # start another instance
```

above code will check each character only one time during whole execution. (I think it's very cpp-style. Isn't it?) So basically Time Complexity would be O(n) where n is the length of string. But be careful! I didn't do any tests on this.